# How to use logging in Python Quart route handler?

Tags: python, quart, hypercorn

I'm new to `hypercorn`+`uvloop`+`quart`. I'm trying to create following files and print some info/debug log in the route handler but nothing shows up. I have debugged into the route handler and noticed the `dog_server.logger.disabled = True`. Does anyone know what's the problem? Thanks!

**dog_blueprint.py**

```
from quart import Blueprint
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class DogBlueprint(Blueprint):
    logger = None
    app_config = None

    def register(self, app, options, first_registration: bool = False):
        # app.logger.info('DogBlueprint is registering')
        print('Blueprint registering...')
        self.logger = app.logger 
        self.logger.info("Hello")  # This one working fine
        self.app_config = app.config
        super(DogBlueprint, self).register(app, options, first_registration)
        self.logger.info("World")  # This one working fine
```

**route.py**

```
dog_server = DogBlueprint('dog_server', __name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

@dog_server.route('/score', methods=['POST'])
async def post_handler():
    received = await _fetch_post_body(request)
    dog_server.logger.info(f'Received size: {len(received)}')  # This one does not work
    ... ...
```

Comment: change ```logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)``` to ```logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)```

Comment: `DEBUG` suppose giving me more logging. But I did try to use `INFO` instead of `DEBUG`. Same result. I even try to print `critical` error message, but still nothing out, because the logger somehow disabled.

Comment: ```dog_server = DogBlueprint('dog_server', __name__)``` When this line is executed, does it calls register function automatically?

Comment: Yes, the `Hello` and `World` could be printed out.

Comment: Instead of ```dog_server.logger.info``` can you try ```DogBlueprint.logger.info``` and see if goes thru. As you defined logger as class variable, see if you are able to make it using the class instead of object.

Comment: It will hit null reference issue: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Hypercorn, see this [discussion](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn/-/issues/154). I'd avoid 0.11.0 and use 0.10.2 or 0.11.1. (I'm the Hypercorn author).

Comment: Verified 0.10.2 working fine for me. Thank you @pgjones